# Drawing a 8x8 rectangle becomes a 9x9 rectangle on screen?

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

```
g2.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 8, 8));
```

This nicely fills a 8x8 rectangle.

But strange things happen when I try to draw a 8x8 rectangle border:

```
g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 8,8));
```

This draws a rectangle 9x9 rectangle.

[image]

But I specified that it should be 8 width and 8 height.

I have a default stroke width 1.

Am I overlooking something? Maybe a better question is: can I turn this off so that I get a 8x8 rectangle when calling draw?

Comment: It is because you wanted a border, try 7,7 instead

Comment: @Zeus That of course will work, but i did specify 8x8 so logic dictates that the result should be 8x8. I did not specify that i wanted a border, i just want a correctly sized rectangle, or does every shape that is given to draw() is ment to be a border? But what if i just want to draw a line2d, that sure isn't a border... Is there any documentation on this subject? It sure puzzles me, but maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: You *are* getting an 8x8 rectangle.  It's inside the border that is being drawn by `draw()`.  The border is outside the specified rectangle size so that if you call both `draw()` and `fill()` using the same object, you get both.

Comment: Fill fills the entire rectangular area, including the area occupied by the border.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of the [`Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) class, in the section titled "Rendering Compatibility Issues", says:

> The JDK(tm) 1.1 rendering model is based on a pixelization model that
>   specifies that coordinates are infinitely thin, lying between the
>   pixels. Drawing operations are performed using a one-pixel wide pen
>   that fills the pixel below and to the right of the anchor point on the
>   path. The JDK 1.1 rendering model is consistent with the capabilities
>   of most of the existing class of platform renderers that need to
>   resolve integer coordinates to a discrete pen that must fall
>   completely on a specified number of pixels.

It goes on to say:

> Java 2D API maintains compatibility with JDK 1.1 rendering behavior,
>   such that legacy operations and existing renderer behavior is
>   unchanged under Java 2D API. Legacy methods that map onto general draw
>   and fill methods are defined,

So basically, this means that if Java renders a line from `(0,0)` to `(0,8)`, it will draw it in the pixels *under* the `0` coordinate. The line from (0,8) to (8,8) will go in the pixl to the *right* of the `8` x coordinate.

```
0┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
 │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │
1├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
2├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
3├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
4├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
5├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
6├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
7├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │ █ │
8├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
 │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │ █ │
 └───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

Thus, using `draw` around an 8x8 rectangle draws two lines inside the rectangle, and two outside it.

Comment: Thanks RealSkeptic, Bubletan and others for the explanation. It becomes more clearer now. But i still find the concept quite confusing, especially when your going with non 1 stroke widths. I'm going to experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of `drawRect` tells you how `Graphics2D` draws rectangles:

> Draws the outline of the specified rectangle. The left and right edges
>   of the rectangle are at x and x + width. The top and bottom edges are
>   at y and y + height. The rectangle is drawn using the graphics
>   context's current color.

So basically, if `x = 0` and `width = 8`, the left line will be at `0` and the right line at `8`. Therefore, the total width is from `0 ... 8`, which equals `8 - 0 + 1 = 9`.

If you want to draw a rectangle which has both width and height `8`, you can just make it smaller by one pixel:

```
g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 7, 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code renders the rectangle twice, first the fill and then the border (draw). That's how it works.

```
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(...);
g2.setColor(Color.white);
g2.fill(rect);
g2.setColor(Color.black);
g2.draw(rect);
```